# SoundStreamPlugin error using DialogFlow in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have tried to implement DialogFlow chatbot in a Flutter app (Codelabs link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dialogflow-flutter) .

After fully completing the codelab, the project has no error. When it runs, the chatbot doesn't show up while a runtime error occurs given below:

*".pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt: (45, 8): Class 'SoundStreamPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener e: /home/devpc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt: (182, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."*

I have tried related StackOverflow solutions but this seems to be a unique problem addressed never before. All credentials are properly setup .

Appreciation in advance .

Answer (score 1):

open

/home/devpc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt

find **onRequestPermissionsResult**, and delete the question mark(**?**).

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>?, grantResults: IntArray?): Boolean {
```

to

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray): Boolean {
```

Comment: Thanks . I have already removed that before posting the question - it wasn't still working .